# Show loading image while running PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been reading the answers on this questions but I can't figure it out. Mostly because I know zero AJAX and javascript.

I have a page with a button, when the user clicks that button... a php script scans a folder in the server and do all kinds of stuff with a database.

I want to show a loading gif while this happens. The user doesn't send information or receive anything, just clicks on a button.

My first try was to send the user to the php file... which is something like this (just an example). And put a div that shows an image while the DOM loads.
But that doesn't work, in fact, it doesn't even show a blank page, I can still see the page in which I click the button and, because the end of the php script has a redirection, I only see the loading icon of the browser as indicator of something happening.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            })
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .loader {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader"></div>
        <!-- PHP SHOULD DO STUFF HERE THEN REDIRECT BACK TO WHERE THE BUTTON WAS CLICKED-->
    </body>
</html>
```

I understand that I have to separate the php part from the "view" part. So my question is... how do a I make the button show a loading gif... while in some way I run the php script from server-side.

I've also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
  $('.loader').show();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'script.php',
   success:function(result){
       $('.loader').hide();
   }
}
</script>
```

But it's not working either. I disabled the redirection on the script and when it finishes running it takes me to that page instead of remaining on the one I made the call from.

Comment: Ajax. There is a lot of tutorials on the internet. Do some research.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript you show is fine, and is the right approach.  Do not redirect anywhere, don't include any other JS.  If I understand this correctly:

> I disabled the redirection on the script and when it finishes running it takes me to that page instead of remaining on the one I made the call from.

you mean that clicking your button sends you to `script.php`.  You haven't included your button HTML, but I guess your button is inside a `<form>`.  When you click it, your jQuery `click` handler is fired, but the form is also being submitted, as it would if you had no Javascript at all.  That will send you on to `script.php`, which is what you are seeing.

You need to stop the default form submission, so that only your Javascript handler is fired.  You can do that as follows:

```
// Event handlers are passed an event object as a parameter
$('#buttonid').click(function(e){

  // Prevent the normal action this event would cause, in this case 
  // submitting the form
  e.preventDefault();

  // ... continue with the rest of your code
  $('.loader').show();
```

More info in [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).